# Why Shutdown Automatic Tomcat after start camunda-bpm-tomcat-7.14.0 in windows

Tags: java, tomcat9, camunda

I use camunda-bpm-tomcat-7.14.0 and connect to Localhost SQL Database (https://medium.com/@ahmedalmahlasi/install-camunda-work-flow-engine-and-integrate-it-with-sqlserver-dba0dab8ae64 )
I have got a problem in connect Camunda to SQL. when I start Camunda, It loads: `http://localhost:8080/camunda-welcome/index.html` but When I click on Cockpit or Admin or Tasklist, …, Cockpit is not load and I see this error: "This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect… " and also Tomcat has closed

What’s a problem? I set `JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15` and `CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\lib`. Is there any problem in path in Environment Variables?

I will be grateful if you help me.

**Edit 1:**
I have got an error in catalina.2020-10-26.log in path "camunda-bpm-tomcat-7.14.0\server\apache-tomcat-9.0.33\logs" : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host XX, named instance \YY/camunda failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434. For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

**Edit 2:**
I can't telnet to XX 1434. I see error: Connecting To XX...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1434: Connect failed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set your CLASSPATH to point to the JDK's lib folder. Remove it and restart Tomcat

Comment: I have got an error in catalina.2020-10-26.log in path "camunda-bpm-tomcat-7.13.0\server\apache-tomcat-9.0.33\logs" : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host ...., named instance \..../camunda failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

Comment: Ok so now your app is running fine but it cannot connect to the SQL server. Can you check that you can telnet to the sql server IP on port 1434?

Comment: I can't telnet to XX 1434. I have got error: Connecting To XX...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1434: Connect failed.

Comment: Then ensure that the SQL Server is running on the selected port. Also ensure that any firewalls between you and the server allow access from Tomcat to the server.